# E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install java8 using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I'm getting an error as follows :

```
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate
```

when I searched the error,  I found out that "WebUpd8" team has officially discontinued there support.
Please help to install oracle java 8. I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I just went through the same process and I fixed the problem by manually installing java 8 on my ubuntu 18.04 machine. Hopefully my answer will help you.

1. Download the latest JAVA 8 SE development kit from here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html
2. Open your terminal.
3. Type `$mkdir /opt/jdk`.
4. Untar Java in your new folder `$tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk`.
5. Set oracle JDK as the default JVM by running those two instructions (or something around that depending on your configuration):

**Note: Each bullet point is one single command**

- `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_<YourVersion>/bin/java 100`
- `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_<YourVersion>/bin/javac 100`

You can check the result by running java -version !

Before I started, I went through those steps as well in order to remove completely java from my system: https://askubuntu.com/questions/84483/how-to-completely-uninstall-java#185250

The source I used for the manual installation of JAVA was this article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps

Comment: I think it would be easier to do a `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and then just choose the alternative for java 8

Comment: Thanks to this wonderful post! It saves my life configuring Elasticsearch in Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help

Comment: This is giving me a `-bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory` error.

Comment: Can you locate Java on your machine?

Comment: just to be more precise the syntax is  :
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "yourinstallpath" 1

with the double quotes

Comment: Updated my answer @docHell

Comment: How to create JAVA_HOME and add Java to the "PATH" in order to use the command "java" in the console, https://vitux.com/how-to-setup-java_home-path-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 32):

Add the following line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

`deb https://debian.opennms.org/ stable main`

Install GPG key of the repository:

`wget -O - http://debian.opennms.org/OPENNMS-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -`

Update the package index:

`sudo apt-get update`

Install oracle-java8-installer deb package:

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

[Source](https://deb.pkgs.org/universal/opennms-stable-amd64/oracle-java8-installer_8u131-1~webupd8~2_all.deb.html)

Answer (score 13):

I was facing the same issue and resolved with this:\

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Answer (score 8):

Please read the details when we execute the below command:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

> The Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16,
>   2019.
>
> The new Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE
>   is substantially different from prior Oracle JDK licenses. The new
>   license permits certain uses, such as personal use and development
>   use, at no cost -- but other uses authorized under prior Oracle JDK
>   licenses may no longer be available. Please review the terms carefully
>   before downloading and using this product. An FAQ is available here:
>   https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html

Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to
download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE
8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java
(and the old links were broken by Oracle).

For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED (unless I find some way around this limitation).

Answer (score 5):

This PPA works (Ubuntu 16.04)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ts.sch.gr/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```