# i'm getting this error while installing jdk8 in ubuntu 18.0.4

Tags: oracle, ubuntu-18.04

```
sensei@sensei-System-Product-Name:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
```

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package `'oracle-java8-installer'` has no installation candidate

What will be issue any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Please read the details when we execute the below command: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

The Oracle JDK License has changed for releases starting April 16, 2019.

The new Oracle Technology Network License Agreement for Oracle Java SE is substantially different from prior Oracle JDK licenses. The new license permits certain uses, such as personal use and development use, at no cost -- but other uses authorized under prior Oracle JDK licenses may no longer be available. Please review the terms carefully before downloading and using this product. An FAQ is available here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/oracle-jdk-faqs.html

Oracle Java downloads now require logging in to an Oracle account to download Java updates, like the latest Oracle Java 8u211 / Java SE 8u212. Because of this I cannot update the PPA with the latest Java (and the old links were broken by Oracle).

For this reason, THIS PPA IS DISCONTINUED

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58214875)